# Does subarray contain a certain value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, sub-array

I have an array like this:

```js
var = [
    {
        "a": "value",
        "b": "value2"
    },
    {
        "a": "value3",
        "b": "value4"
    }
    ...
]
```

I need to find if any of the subarrays contain a certain value.

I tried

```js
var.flat().includes("value")
```

but that always returned false for some reason and `.flat()` didn't even flatten the array.

I also tried

```js
var.includes("value")
```

without the `.flat()` but that would only return if the top level includes it.

I could do

```js
var = [
    "a": [
        "value",
        "value3"
        ...
    ],
    "b": [
        "value2",
        "value4"
        ...
    ]
]
```

but I'd rather not since that'd require me to rewrite some code I already wrote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Comment: @lbragile no, that will only return if the top level includes it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flatMap` to extract all nested values into a single flat array first:

```js
const objs = [
    {
        "a": "value",
        "b": "value2"
    },
    {
        "a": "value3",
        "b": "value4"
    }
];
const values = objs.flatMap(Object.values);
console.log(values.includes("value"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Could I have some clarification on how this works? Specifically, how is ```.flatMap()``` different from ```.flat()```

Comment: @RedGuy11 See [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: @RedGuy11 `Object.values` takes an object and extracts its values as an array. `flatMap` maps an array, then calls `.flat()` on the resulting mapped array. It's like `.map` followed by `.flat`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ok, thanks. But dosen't ```.map()``` need a callback (that's what the link @SaymoinSam shared said)

Comment: @RedGuy11 `Object.values` is the callback. It gets called for every iteration and returns an array of values. Then `.flat` flattens the array of arrays of values.

Comment: @CertainPerformace ohhhhhhh I get it now tysm!

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate with `some` (it would stop the loop immediately when encounter the first `value`), combine with `Object.values` (get array of values from an object) and `.includes` (to check if the array has `value`),

```js
const data = [
  {
    a: "value",
    b: "value2",
  },
  {
    a: "value3",
    b: "value4",
  },
];

const valid = data.some((d) => Object.values(d).includes("value"));

console.log(valid);
```

Comment: This is much better than reduce.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `varr` is already flatten array of objects. Since you want to check in Object values. Use `varr.map(Object.values).flat()`

```js
varr = [
  {
    a: "value",
    b: "value2",
  },
  {
    a: "value3",
    b: "value4",
  },
];

console.log(varr.map(Object.values).flat().includes("value"));
```